# NUXT pass object data into pages with path

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm really new to Vue and Nuxt so I apologise if this is a simple question.

I'm generating my routes dynamically on making an API call for my data on Index.vue. One API call is enough for me to retrieve all the data i need which is stored in `deals_array`, so I don't need another API call on my individual page, I just need the data from each `deal` in `deals_array`.

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="deal of deals_array" :key="deal.id">
    <nuxt-link :to="getSlug(deal)">{{ deal.name }}, {{deal.value}}</nuxt-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm wondering how do I pass the entire `deal` object into my pages, so that when I click on the individual `nuxt-link` I would be able to access that deal object and all its attributes (for each page).

I've taken a look at passing `params` into nuxt-link but I understand that it only pairs with `name` attribute and not the `path`, where I need the `path` URL in this case.

I may be doing this entirely wrong so I'm hoping to be pointed in the right direction.

Edit - getSlug function

```js
getSlug(deal) {
      let name = deal.name;
      let dealDetails = deal.details;
      let name_hyphen = name.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
      let deal_hyphen = dealDetails.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
      let nameDealSlug = name_hyphen + "-" + deal_hyphen;
      // remove selected special characters from slug
      let clean_nameDealSlug = nameDealSlug.replace(
        /[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g,
        ""
      );

      let finalSlug = `deals/${clean_nameDealSlug}`;
      return finalSlug;
    }
```

Comment: how does getSlug looks like? is this your API call

Comment: getSlug is a function that uses the deal object to generate a unique URL, not an API call, added in my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have gone through this: https://router.vuejs.org/api/.

You can just pass the entire object:

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ path: 'test', query: {a: 1, b: 2}}">Test Page</nuxt-link>
```

And your URL will become something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/test?a=1&b=2
```

The entire object can be simply passed.

This will be available to your next page in $route object in the url query.

Otherwise if you don't want to get your deal object exposed just use the concepts of vuex. Store the entire deal object in the vuex and pass ids to different pages. And from pages retrieve the deal object through vuex.

Comment: What if I dont' want it exposed in the URL?

Comment: Nope, I would want the path parameter instead

Comment: I don't know whether this is a good idea or not, but if you want something like this then you can store the deal object in the store (vuex). Just pass the deal ID to the pages and from the pages try to retrieve the deal object through the store.

Comment: Right, that is exactly what I landed and am trying now. Just wanted to check whether there were other ways of doing this, thanks alot

Comment: Edited my answer, to meet your requirements.